# Distinguishing between hosts in asynchronous HTTP responses

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, jquery-deferred, deferred

Is it possible to determine from which location a given HTTP response came from, out of a series of asynchronously-received responses?

If that seems like a mouthful, I'm with you. But I think an example might clear up the question.

Here's the situation: I'm sending some AJAX requests to different locations, which might be internal (on the same server) or external (on a different server). Let's call these locations *one* and *two*. And, for the record, I'm using jQuery `Deferred` objects to handle the requests.

What I want to be able to do is associate each response with the location it came from while keeping the requests asynchronous.

So if, let's say, *one* returns `{ "success":"true"}` and *two* returns a 500 error, what is the easiest way to determine that *one* succeeded and *two* failed in the callback?

This is a trivial problem when requests are sent synchronously: Send *one* and wait for the response. Then send *two* and wait for the response. And so on, for any number of locations. The connection between resource and response is clear. But this isn't a very good solution for *n* requests.

This issue I'm having seems to arise when you send data asynchronously. The responses of a group of Promises are just lumped together and made indistinguishable. And when you look at them individually, the only data you've got in the callbacks are the [HTTP response headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html), which seem to say nothing about where the request came from.

Is there any way to determine, for any number of asynchronous requests, where the response comes from, using jQuery Deferreds?

And one last technical detail: I am using the [Amplify.js request method](http://amplifyjs.com/api/request/) with the [Deferred plugin](https://github.com/elijahmanor/amplify-request-deferred), which is just a fancy coat on top of the jQuery ajax method and jQuery Deferreds.

Comment: Inspect the properties on the jqXHR, i'd be surprised if there isn't something there you can use.

Comment: Also, depending on your code, `this` should be the options passed into the ajax request, therefore you could use `this.url` to see it.

Comment: @KevinB, I also thought the jqXHR object would have something useful in it, but it (surprisingly) doesn't seem to! Right now my `this` is the window, but that suggestion is a good line of thinking to go down. I'll see if I can access anything in the callback from other sources than just what the response gives me. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: There's no need to inspect anything that comes back from the servers. By making each request and handling its response within a unique execution context (ie. closure), the request URL and its response are automatically associated with each other. Nothing fancy and nothing clever is required. Your code may already do this but I don't know as there's no code in the question.